# Rails view, undefined method `empty?' for a datetime object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, view, erb

So i was modifying my index view as to make it only render specific fields based on an instance variable named fields, but when i did this it worked just fine except for the datetime field that generates an error. example :`undefined method empty?' for Tue, 22 Nov 2016 23:01:00 +0000:DateTime` Here's the view code.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Articles</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <% @fields = ["headline", "content","date", "locale", "classification" ]  unless @fields.present? %>
    <tr>
      <% @fields.each do |field| %>
        <th><%= "#{field.titleize}" %></th>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <tr>
        <% @fields.each do |field| %>
        <td><%= simple_format article.send(field) %></td>
        <% end %>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', article %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Article', new_article_path %>
```

And here's the model code

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  validates :classification,
    :inclusion  => { :in => [ 'unclassified', 'medical', 'non medical'] }
  validates :headline, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true
  field :headline, type: String
  field :content, type: String
  field :classification, type: String
  field :weak_classification, type: String
  field :locale, type: String
  field :date, type: DateTime
end
```

How can i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the fields to `string` before.

```
<%= simple_format article.send(field).to_s %>
```

Or will be better check a type of a field and format it.

```
def format_article_field(field)
  value = article.send(field)

  if value.kind_of?(DateTime)
    value.to_s(:short) # any format shortcut here
  else
    simple_format(value.to_s)
  end
end

<%= format_article_field field %>
```